# How to left-justify the graph in graphviz

Tags: graphviz

I have a graph.

```
digraph {
    graph [rankdir=RL]
    b -> a
    c
}
```

[image]

I want to have the flow of the arrows from right to left, but I want to justify the unconnected nodes to the left. In the example `c` should snap to the left edge of the image, same as `a`.

Is there a way do this without subgraphs?

Comment: You wrote: "I want to have the flow of the arrows from left to right" shouldn't this be "I want to have the flow of the arrows from right to left"?

Comment: Have a look at the `rank` possibilities e.g. `    {rank = same; a; c;}`

Comment: @albert, thank you, I fixed it to say "from right to left".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have the layout of LR, but arrows pointing other way, you can do it like this:

- Set the `rankdir` to `LR`
- add the `dir=back` attribute to the edges which you want to be reversed.

For your example:

```
digraph {
    graph [rankdir=LR]
    b -> a [dir=back]
   c
}
```

Result:

[image]